# Which Database to use for massive update

Tags: database, database-design, bigdata, nosql

I need help in select the right Database for my data.
I have table of usersItems with the following columns:

```
userId , itemId , attribute1 ,attribute2,attribute3 .......,attribute10
```

There are 1000 users +- , and every user has 100,000 items(avg) . 
The data in the table updated every 3 hours from  third-party API. (I'm getting file for each user with the updated items.. not all of them really changed).

The data from this table in use as is, without aggregations. Each user can see his items in the website.

Today I'm using mySQL and have few problems with the massive update of records.
I thought to migrate the data to redshift or  one of the NOSQL dbs.

I'll be happy to hear your recommendations.

Comment: How big is your data (in GB)? What is the size (in GB) of the update every 3 hours? On the information given your data seems quite modest in size (100 million rows plus the updates). I suggest you try improving the performance under MySQL before you consider switching to another DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com) but this kind of work-load. This is what we've been using over here and we are quite happy with it. It's an **open source** NoSQL database that is designed for both in-memory and solid state disk-operation. It can handle a lot of IOPS (100k+ IOPS in-memory, like Redis), if you manage to avoid ultra-hot keys (more than 1000 IOPS on single 'rows'). It can be configured to replicate all data and has synchronic (SSD only) as well as asynchronic (HDD) persistence support.

For your use case, you'd have to decide whether lists can be bound in size to 128k - 1MB or whether you need infinite growable lists per user. This will make the difference between using a normal list (limited to record size, 128k-1M) or using a large ordered list (infinite). Note that you overcome your MySQL-limitations at the moment that you start having a single primary key for the list you are trying to query. No joins or anything is required. It only get's a bit fuzzy if list entries need their own primary key (e.g. m:n relations) - however, there's concepts that work around that like de-normalization.

When you give it a few days of figuring out what works best, Aerospike can help you with consistently low latencies that only a product grown up in AdSpace can offer. You might not need it right now, but we found that working with SSDs gives us a lot more freedom in terms of what we store due to the much higher capacity compared to memory.

Other options I'd evaluate would be Redis or Couchbase - if asynchronous persistence is not an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try an in-memory database with persistence: Redis, CouchBase, Tarantool, Aerospike.

Each of them should handle your workload of heavy updates. This works because these databases don't change the table space on each update, but rather append to the transaction log only. Which is the fastest possible way to persist updates.

So if your update workload is less than 100Mb/sec (the speed of linear writing of a spinning disk) then those databases should help you.

But everything depends on your specific workload though. You can test all of those databases and choose the best one.